# Normalising higher moments of features for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

It's quite common to normalise different feature vectors so that they have the same mean and variance (usually `(X-mean(X))/sd(X)`), so that the changes in the smaller variables aren't swamped.

Is the same ever done for higher moments (skewness, kurtosis, ...), for data where those moments are extreme? If so, are there any precautions that need to be taken before doing so?

Edit: the question is fairly general, I should qualify that I'm doing clustering analysis, and would love answers relating to the field. However, more general answers are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

[Bootstrap](http://orm.sagepub.com/content/3/2/166.short) is in the presence of skewed dependent variables and kurtosis.

Besides, transformations are another good strategy. The most often used transformation, [Box-Cox transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Cox_transformation#Box.E2.80.93Cox_transformation), is a useful technique used to stabilize variance, make the data more normal distribution-like, and improve the validity of measures of association.

If you are using log transformations, but your data contains zeros, this article ([Transforming data with zeros](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/transformations/)) summarized some effective transformations that might helpful.

Comment: Ah, I'd never bothered looking in to power transformations before, thanks for the pointer. I added an addendum to my question, because I realised my question was more general than intended.